# How to convert curl into python

Tags: python-3.x, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I am reading the instagram api , there is command of curl , I have been trying to read through what curl -F means, but somehow I am getting nowhere...

Appreciate if anyone can provide any insight on this topic.

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

-F is for --form, but for most curl tasks I will often enter the curl into a web converter. 
Check out https://curl.trillworks.com/

Looks like there is a library that does it too, but I've not used it: https://github.com/spulec/uncurl